# Google Sheets Point System

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering if there was a way to add points in a column in Google Sheets, so if someone entered 1 in Column D it would give it 5 points and spit out a 5 in column H. so if someone were to enter 1 in a 5 point column and 5 in a 3 point column it would spit out the total of 20. Anything would help thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I don't suppose you mean a formula that multiplies the value in the "5" column by 5 and multiples the value in the "3" column by 3, and sums the products.